# $F(x) = 2x + 4^{-x}$ . Show that the tangent to the curve with $y = F(x)$ at the point at $(-1,y)$ is $15(\ln 2) x + 2y + 15(\ln 2) - 9 = 0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

I am struggling to manipulate the following into the required solution

[image]

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slope of the tangent to a curve can be found by differentiating the function:
\begin{align}
F(x)&=2x+4^{-x}\\
F'(x)&=2-\ln4\cdot4^{-x}\\
F'(-1)&=2-\ln4\cdot4\\
F'(-1)&=2-8\ln2
\end{align}

Once we have the slope, we can find the point:
\begin{align}
y=F(-1)&=-2+4\\
y&=2 \Rightarrow (-1,2)
\end{align}

Substitute the point and the slope into the equation of a line:
\begin{align}
y-y_1&=m(x-x_1)\\
y-2&=(2-8\ln2)(x+1)\\
y-2&=(2-8\ln2)x+2-8\ln2\\
0&=(2-8\ln2)x-y+4-8\ln2
\end{align}

There must be a mistake in the question.  [View on desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/woh5pjcs3u).

---

The given function should instead be
$$F(x)=2^x+4^{-x}.$$

Below, the same steps with a different function.
\begin{align}
F(x)&=2^x+4^{-x}\\
F(x)&=2^x+2^{-2x}\\
F'(x)&=\ln2\cdot2^x-2\ln2\cdot2^{-2x}\\
F'(-1)&=\ln2\cdot\frac12-2\ln2\cdot2^2\\
F'(-1)&=-\frac{15}2\ln2
\end{align}

\begin{align}
y=F(-1)&=\frac12+4\\
y&=\frac92\Rightarrow(-1,\frac92)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
y-y_1&=m(x-x_1)\\
y-\frac92&=-\frac{15}2\ln2\cdot(x+1)\\
2y-9&=-15\ln2\cdot(x+1)\\(15\ln2)x+2y-9+15\ln2&=0
\end{align}

[View on desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y7rlfxaokx).

Comment: Hi, I think your right because the solution for the question states y = -2 when x=-1. Thanks for seeing this.

Comment: Found the problem.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you.